# Preselect the flag reason for already flagged posts

Tags: feature-request, flags

We've got this new shiny flag overview where we can *flag or disagree*.

It would be nice if the previous flagging reason would be preselected, this would make it much easier to agree with a flag.

Comment: But it would make it harder to disagree... And make it possible to accept an unwanted flag by clicking absentmindedly.

Answer (score 12):

Bad idea, preselecting based on the most popular reason just introduces herd-think. **You should decide for yourself** if and why the post should be flagged and not just automatically  follow what others may think.

I already see problems with this when users see questions with just one vote to close. Often it's the kiss of death for a perfectly on topic good question as soon as that `close (1)` appears - rewrite rule closers, I'm looking at *you* :).

Comment: Agreed. In fact I've wondered if the existing reasons shouldn't even be shown and only if closers votes add up to a consensus with the same close reason should they be acted on! Actually as a high rep user on some sites I've learned a lot from seeing how others voted, but I've also caught myself just going "oh ya" and clicking through. Pre-selecting would definitely just make this worse.

Comment: Regardless of the underlying consensus, if a post has hit the close threshold then there's something wrong with it and it does need to be closed - even of the reasons are spread across the choices. However sometimes I think that you should only get to see the other closers reasons **after** you've cast your vote. I think that would make people think for themselves a bit more.

Comment: Agreed. The same logic could even be used for seeing the total close vote count before you've cast your vote.

Comment: @Caleb (and Kev) one counter-point to this is duplicates. We can't realistically expect every close-voter to hunt for and find a duplicate link, so having previously suggested duplicates available to select from is probably a positive here, otherwise how many closers will be lazy and pick something else?

Comment: @dma - you make a very good point there.